# How to correct tbn for files with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, video-quality

I have the following files (all .mp4). Whenever I want to concatenate them, the timestamps apparently get broken. Is there a way to correct those files with transcoding?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to transcode, it can be done via remuxing.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -video_track_timescale 30 out.mp4
```

where 30 is the new tbn value.